# The right way to use the new pyspark.pandas?

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks

This recent blog post from Databricks https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html says that the only change needed to a pandas program to run it under pyspark.pandas is to change `from pandas import read_csv` to `from pyspark.pandas import read_csv`.

But that does not seem right. What about all the other (non `read_csv`) references to pandas? Isn't the right approach to change `import pandas as pd` to `import pyspark.pandas as pd`? Then all the other pandas references in your existing program will point to the pyspark version of pandas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got that right. The canonical way they have suggested, however, is, `from pyspark import pandas as ps`

Comment: Thanks. I can test that. So that means going through my entire program and changing all pd to ps? Not exactly a one line change.

Comment: That line does not work. It results in the error... ImportError: cannot import name 'pandas' from 'pyspark.pandas' (/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/pandas/__init__.py)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited the answer!

Comment: The above works. But for my code I decided that it is more clear to use pspd (PySpark pandas) instead of ps. This distinguishes PySpark.pandas from PySpark itself.