# Pyspark-pandas not working on Spark 3.1.2

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using spark 3.1.2 and attempting to use [pyspark-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69730073/the-right-way-to-use-the-new-pyspark-pandas). However when attempting `from pyspark import pandas as ps` I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'pandas' from 'pyspark' (/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/__init__.py)
```

How can I utilize this package? (For reference, I am using databricks).

Answer (score 0):

Databricks Runtime 10.0.0+ is required for `pyspark-pandas` with spark 3.2+

Comment: But you said you needed it to work with Spark 3.1.2, not with 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe follow these steps from the Google dataproc version: [How to run spark 3.2.0 on google dataproc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70254378/how-to-run-spark-3-2-0-on-google-dataproc)

I think the solution here is to upgrade Databricks to the latest version after Spark 3.2 release last October 2021.

I am using EMR 6.5 and it still does not have Spark 3.2 thus we cannot use this yet either.  Reading the proposal to add Pandas support shows there are other implementations that may work for me: Dask, Modin, and Koalas. See the proposal [here](https://hyp.is/go?url=https%3A%2F%2Fissues.apache.org%2Fjira%2Fbrowse%2FSPARK-34849&group=__world__).